# With DATE_TRUNC('week'), Return a record if the week's .sum(:points) has 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following Rails+Postgres query to query the db for an aggregate number of points and grouped by week:

```
Log Table: id, user_id, points, created_at

points_by_week = Log.where(user_id: user_id).group("DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at)", "DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").sum(:points)
```

This returns results like so:

```
{ [2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, 2017-04-17 00:00:00 UTC]=>10, 
  [2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, 2017-05-15 00:00:00 UTC]=>110, 
  [2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, 2017-06-19 00:00:00 UTC]=>1185 }
```

The problem is this only returns a record if 1 or more points exist per the week.

**How can I:**

1. Have a week result return if the week contains 0 points. Example, for the return above, the week of `2017-05-08` is missing because it has 0 points. I want it to return above. So when I graph this result, the week shows 0.
2. Specify how many weeks to go back? And make sure if a week contains 0 points, it is outputted per #1 above.

Thank you

Comment: In the week `2017-05-08`, is points `0` or `nil` ?

Comment: nil, no records exist for that week in this case...

Comment: to be clear there is no result returned for that week, it just skips that week as seen above in the return results I provided.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I strongly recommend to start learning and using plain SQL to perform such tasks. Active Record (like any other ORM) is good only for simple tasks. Sooner or later you will need to dig into Postgres logs and find what exact SQL queries your RoR AR has produced, why they are not optimal or why these queries give you now what you want.

Now regarding your question itself. I would do it like this, using LEFT JOIN and CTE (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with dates(period) as (
  select generate_series
  from generate_series(
    '2017-01-01'::timestamp,
    now(),
    interval '1 week'
  )
)
select
  period,
  points
from
  dates
left join log_table on date_trunc('week', created_at) = date_trunc('week', period)
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

CTE are standard SQL feature and they are really worth to learn and use.

To work with data in the database, consider using database (SQL) first.

There is even an ideology with increasing popularity -- #DatabaseFirst.

If you have doubts here are some good articles related to this topic:

http://database-programmer.blogspot.co.at/2010/12/historical-perspective-of-orm-and.html?m=1

http://tapoueh.org/blog/2017/06/sql-and-business-logic/

http://tapoueh.org/blog/2017/06/how-to-write-sql/

Comment: Solution is good, but that join will not work because timestamps produced by `generate_series` and `date_trunc` won't match if you start from 2017-01-01. You need to `date_trunc('week'` your starting date.

Comment: @Nick I find plain SQL in an ORM like this to be out of place. `Arel` the underlying query assembler for rails/activerecord can assemble any valid SQL using code rather than plain strings. Also in most cases it allows you to merge the results into a true AR Object

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you. Is there a way to do this w rails?

Comment: @nick I appreciate the reply but would love to find a Rails way of doing this....

Comment: @AnnaSm I have posted an answer although I am certain it may be confusing it should return the results requested. **Nick** thank you for the suggested SQL it made creating the query a bit simpler when I didn't have to figure out how to generate the weeks (I don't use postgres much)

Comment: Here is a good fresh article explaining that generation of dates: http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2017/06/08/working-with-time-in-postgres/

Comment: generate_series() is a standard built-in function, very useful to generate series of integers or dates.

Comment: AnnaSm, again (I won't stop to say it) -- learn plain SQL and use it in advanced cases. And just use AR's "execute" method.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree that this is complex enough to warrant using SQL or Arel. You have 95% of the result you need right there, and the rest should be trivial.

## Method 1

If you only want to be able to fetch values from the Hash, consider defining a default value on the hash like this:

```
points_by_week =
  Hash.
  new(0).
  merge(
    Log.
    where(user_id: user_id).
    group("DATE_TRUNC('year', created_at)", "DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)").
    sum(:points)
  )
```

Then, whenever you call:

```
points_by_week[x]
```

... you will be returned a 0 if x is not in the hash.

If a nil is required for keys not present then you would pass `nil` instead of `0` to Hash.new

## Method 2

Alternatively, if you really need to populate the entire set of values in the hash, you can create a hash with the required keys and zeroes/nils for the values with something like this, based on a range (I've used integers 0 to 100 here):

```
Hash[*(0..5).to_a.zip(Array.new(6,0)).flatten]
 => {0=>0, 1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0}
```

... or ...

```
Hash[*(0..5).to_a.zip(Array.new(6)).flatten]
 => {0=>nil, 1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil}
```

(maybe there's a more convenient way), and `#reverse_merge` it with your current hash.

e.g.

```
2.2.5 :036 > x = {1 => 1, 3 => 3}
 => {1=>1, 3=>3} 
2.2.5 :037 > y = Hash[*(0..5).to_a.zip(Array.new(6,0)).flatten]
 => {0=>0, 1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0} 
2.2.5 :038 > z = x.reverse_merge(y)
 => {0=>0, 1=>1, 2=>0, 3=>3, 4=>0, 5=>0}
```

An array of Monday dates can be generated with something like:

```
mondays = (Date.parse("2017-04-17")..(Date.parse("2017-04-17")+20.weeks)).map(&:to_time).select(&:monday?)
```

... and transformed to [year,date] pairs with ...

```
year_monday_pairs = mondays.map{|d| [d.beginning_of_year, d] }
```

... and converted to the hash required for the `#reverse_merge` with ...

```
Hash[*year_monday_pairs.zip(Array.new(year_monday_pairs.size, 0)).flatten(1)]
 => {[2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-04-17 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-04-24 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-05-01 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-05-08 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-05-15 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-05-22 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-05-29 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-06-05 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-06-12 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-06-19 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-06-26 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-03 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-10 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-17 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-24 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-31 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-08-07 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-08-14 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-08-21 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-08-28 00:00:00 +0100]=>0, [2017-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, 2017-09-04 00:00:00 +0100]=>0}
```

Comment: Since `nil` is the intended result `Hash.new(0)` is not really needed (Although it does seem more correct) but I can agree that I may have over thought the solution as a reaction to the original answer. As a side note maybe alter your query to address point 2. Additionally it might be useful to explain how to build a range of "weeks" for iterative purposes

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, noted. Updated to reflect your helpful comments.

Comment: Already upvoted or I would upvote again. Very clean simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Please be advised I did not take the time to recreate your structure.

**Warning For Other Readers**

> Older versions of Arel do not assemble CTE statements. (I have had issues with versions < 6.0 the methods are there  but for some reason the "With" portion of the query does not get generated) For these versions use sub-queries rather than CTE.

The first thing I would do for this type of functionality is create a service object to handle this specific case. (So let's start there)

```
class UserPointsByWeek
  attr_reader :user


  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end
end
```

Now for the heavy lifting to build the appropriate query (BTW Thank @Nick for his contribution as I built this based on his suggestion along with @ŁukaszKamiński comment)

```
class UserPointsByWeek
  attr_accessor :weeks_back
  # ...
  # results returned as an Array of Hashes 
  # [{week: ####-##-##, weekly_points: N},{week: ####-##-##, weekly_points: N}]
  def weekly_points
    @points_by_week ||= ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(to_sql).to_hash
  end
  #Show the SQL generated
  def to_sql
    result.to_sql
  end


  private
    #This is the actual query that will be executed
    def result
      all_weeks.project(
        all_weeks[:week],
        log_table[:points].sum.as('weekly_points')
      ).with([first_week_table,all_weeks_table]).
      join(log_table,Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(
        all_weeks[:week].eq(
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_TRUNC',
            [
              Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'week'"),
              log_table[:created_at]
            ])
          ).and(log_table[:user_id].eq(@user.id))
      ).group(
        all_weeks[:week]
      )
    end

    def rollback
      if @weeks_back 
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_TRUNC',[
             Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'week'"),
             Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'#{@weeks_back.weeks.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}'::timestamp")
         ]) 
      else 
         first_week.project(first_week[:week].minimum)
      end
    end

    # the logs table that actually exists in your database
    def log_table
      Log.arel_table
    end

    # just a table alias
    def first_week 
      Arel::Table.new('first_week')
    end
    # definition for the table alias
    def first_week_table
      Arel::Nodes::As.new(first_week,first_week_definition)
    end

    # definition for finding @user's weeks on record
    # we will call use MIN later on to determine the First Week
    def first_week_definition
      log_table.project(
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('DATE_TRUNC',[
            Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'week'"),
            log_table[:created_at]
          ]).as('week')
      ).where(log_table[:user_id].eq(@user.id))
    end

    #just a table alias
    def all_weeks 
      Arel::Table.new('all_weeks')
    end

    #a definition for this alias
    def all_weeks_table
      Arel::Nodes::As.new(all_weeks,series_table)
    end

    # series generation as suggested by @Nick
    # used to build all_weeks_table
    def series_table
      Arel::SelectManager.new(Arel::Table.engine,series_definition)
        .project(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("gs").as('week'))
    end

    # the actual series being generated
    # starts on the @user's first week and continues to now on 1 week intervals
    def series_definition
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('generate_series',
        [ rollback,
          Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("now()"),
          Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("interval '1 week'")
        ]
      ).as('_(gs)')
    end
end
```

The resulting SQL for this will look like

```
UserPointsByWeek.new(@user).to_sql # Assuming user.id == 1
#=> "WITH first_week AS (
        SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', logs.created_at) AS week 
        FROM logs 
        WHERE logs.user_id = 1
    ), all_weeks AS (
        SELECT gs AS week 
        FROM generate_series(
            (SELECT MIN(first_week.week) FROM first_week), 
            now(), 
            interval '1 week') AS _(gs)
   ) 
   SELECT 
       all_weeks.week, 
       SUM(logs.points) AS weekly_points 
   FROM 
       all_weeks 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN logs ON all_weeks.week = DATE_TRUNC('week', logs.created_at) 
         AND logs.user_id = 1    
   GROUP BY 
       all_weeks.week"
```

And `#weekly_points` will return an `Array` of `Hash` objects with 2 keys `:week` and `:weekly_points` for each week between the User's first week and the current week. As a side note the `user` is also still accessible as well.

Comment: @Nick yes harder to read for sure but ensures SQL escaping, extensibility (could be separated into common components for use in other queries) and is far easier to debug

Comment: "send" / "execute" with whole SQL and SQL escaping are not mutually exclusive things. While splitting well-readable SQL to chunks makes it non-readable and increases maintenance costs (to analyze and optimize SQL, you'll need to grep logs, trace proper queries somehow, and then deal with plain SQL eventually).

Comment: "far easier to debug" -- sorry no. Debugging SQL and its performance in such approach is a nightmare.

Comment: @Nick to each their own. I have built massive reporting libraries based on `Arel` composition (outside of rails) that are extremely extensible and maintainable but thank you for chiming in